# Не отображается placeholder в Mozilla

Tags: html, css, google-chrome-devtools, firefox-devtools

Почему внутри инпутов, в Мозиле не отображаются placeholder-ы, как это происходит в др. браузерах? Не могу стилизовать, может где-то настроить надо в Мозиле что-то?

Инспектор гугла (placeholder отображается)

[image: Скриншот инспектора Гугла]

Инспектор мозилы (placeholder не отображается)

[image: Скриншот инспектора Мозиллы]

Comment: Приведите часть кода текстом (не картинкой) для демонстрации проблемы...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решено путем включения теневого dom в Mozilla.

Введите about:config в адресной строке браузера.

Установите параметр "devtools.inspector.showAllAnonymousContent" , в значение true.

Готово. Теперь вам доступен теневой dom, а внутри него и placeholder.

[image: Скриншот]